# Maven plugin execution change Maven properties or skip build lifecycle steps

Tags: maven, lifecycle, maven-gae-plugin

When I build my application with maven, I run `mvn clean install`. As a part of the install lifecycle, I run `appengine:devserver_start` from [Google's GAE Maven plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). This appears to be already bound to a step in the lifecycle and therefore it reruns some build steps from the beginning, even though me running `mvn install` did those. For example, the resources step is rerun. I had my own Java script run to download the latest resources for my build. But because of `appengine:devserver_stop`, I need to uselessly run this cript again because the resources step is re-executed.

I can think of two ways I can avoid this, but I'm not sure how to configure both ways. The first would be to somehow skip re-running build steps that I've already run. The other way would be to change the Maven POM properties just for the plugin execution. I have a Maven property set, either to `true` or `false`, that I can use to set the `skip` setting for the Java script I use during resources (because I run this script using the **exec-maven-plugin**). Think of this as a Maven property that can be set with the *-D* flag. Can I have this property changed just for the plugin?

If you are having trouble thinking about my scenario, consider what happens when you run `mvn compile install`. All build lifecycle steps until `compile` will run, then all compile steps until `install` will run, including `compile`.

Answer (score 1):

A common/easy way to solve this kind of problems is to use [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Just create a new profile that includes the plugin with preferred phases.

Comment: That's good information to know, but still doesn't answer about how I can get the Maven plugin to not execute previous steps in the build lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably don't fight with it and just run `clean appengine:devserver_start` instead of `clean install`. Read my answer here for a more detailed explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638442/2464295